# AWS lambda api Postgres not won’t insert

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following AWS lambda handler:

```
exports.handler = async (event, data) => {
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');
  const awsParamStore = require('aws-param-store');
  const {
    Pool
  } = require('pg');
  var host;


  await awsParamStore.getParameter('testing-main-rds-url', { //get database host from AWS
      region: 'us-east-1'
    })
    .then((parameter) => {
      host = parameter.Value
    });

  var signer = await new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    username: 'developer',
    hostname: host,
    port: 5432
  });

  var token = await signer.getAuthToken({}); //get token from AWS


  const db = await new Pool({
    user: "developer",
    host: host,
    database: "main",
    password: token,
    port: 5432,
    ssl: true,
  });


  const query = `INSERT INTO crm.user_crm
   (u_id,username)
   VALUES ($1,$2)`;
  const values = [event.u_id, event.username];


db.connect((err, client, release) => {
  if (err) {
    throw("Error acquiring client.", err.stack);
  } else {
    client.query(query, values, (err, result) => {
      release();
      if (err) {
        throw("Error executing query.", err.stack);
        return ;
      } else {
        console.log("INSERT DONE");
        db.end()
        return {
            statusCode: 200
        };
      }
    })
  }
})
};
```

This code will take in data and add it to a database.
When I run it on my computer with `console.log(require('./index').handler(data));` it works perfectly and inserts the record. When I run it from lambda it returns nothing and doesn’t insert a record. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything in Cloudwatch? Does your Lambda role have the required permissions etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixing `async/await` with `callback` style. Your lambda function will finish before the query finish.

As example in [pg document](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) it supports `async/await`:
Instead of `db.connect((err, client, release) => {...`

```
const res = await pool.query(query, values);
console.log("INSERT DONE");
await pool.end()
return {
  statusCode: 200
};
```